# How to escape a invalid string using regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I have below string, which is being escaped incorrectly.

```
 "\"name\":\"\"/test/name=testame\" 001\""
```

I would like to use regular expression to find strings contain above pattern and replace it with the correct escape pattern. At the moment, I'm using hard coding to find and replace the string, which is not what I want.

PS: I've no control of above string pattern. I'll have to handle the incorrectness in my application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "*which is being escaped incorrectly*"? It seems like correctly escaped string `String s = "\"name\":\"\"/test/name=testame\" 001\"";`.

Comment: @Pshemo guessing it should be `"\"name\":\"'/test/name=testame' 001\""`

Comment: Please include the correct (desired) output.

Comment: @PeterTurner It is possible, but just to be sure I would rather see explanation from OP.

Comment: It's good context, but I don't think actually matters for answering the question.  I think the problem is there's no pattern to go off of and we can't be expected to just make one up

Comment: As @PeterTurner pointed out the problem is with this part testame\" 001\", especially when you parse it to Java Object using JSON lib. 

I would like to be converted to what PeterTurner suggested or something like this:
\"name\":\"/test/name=testame 001\"

Comment: @diplomaticguru This information should be part of your question. Explain how this string is *invalid* and what you would like valid string to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help:

- `\\` finds `\`
- `\"` finds "
- `[a-zA-Z_-]+` is probably enough to match your labels and names
- `[0-9]+` will probably match that number without screwing it up or finding too much
- `:` and `=` are literals and don't need escaping

put 'em together and you've got yourself a night regular expression.

I don't see anything in this question that would prohibit you doing substitution using parenthesis, but you didn't say what tool you're using to do the replacing so I can't give you many hints.  Usually you'll put

```
(PART 1 OF REGEXP)SOME LITERAL YOU HATE(PART 2 OF REGEXP)
```

as your matcher and

```
\1SOME LITERAL YOU LIKE\2
```

as your substitution string. If you were going to do it with perl you'd use

```
s\MATCHER\SUBSTITUTER\g.
```

You could do it with a perl one-liner, but you'd have to be double careful in re-escaping your quotes.

Comment: Thank you @PeterTurner, that'll do nicely. Your detailed explanation is much appreciated. cheers.

Comment: In Java accessing match from group `x` is done via `$x`, not `\x`. Also groups are indexed from `1` (group `0` represents match of entire regex).

Comment: @Pshemo I think you're right in general, that was how I did it using RAD studio, now that I'm using perl a lot more I'm getting myself confused. He'll figure out what happened when the entire string shows up there I suppose...